# Parse several formats' date in Java 8

Tags: date, java-8, lazy-evaluation

I need to convert a date from a old format to a new format in Java 8, there are several old formats, so it converts the date with the first matched format. How can I do it? Thanks a lot.

```
String oldFormat1 = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
String oldFormat2 = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
String newFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

try {
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat1);
  Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
  format.applyPattern(newFormat);
  String newDateString = format.format(date);
  return source;
} catch (ParseException e) {
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat2);
  Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
  format.applyPattern(newFormat);
  String newDateString = format.format(date);
  return source;
  ...
}
```

**Solution**
As mentioned below, I used DateTimeFormatter and LocalDateTime to realize the function.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldFormat1))
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldFormat2))
            .toFormatter();
        DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(newFormat);

        try {
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
            String source = newFormatter.format(dateTime);
            return " - " + source;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            log.error("Wrong date: {}", dateStr);
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat` if you are using java 8, use `LocalDateTime` with `DateTimeFormatter` instead

Comment: Thank you @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks, I got it.

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldFormat1))
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldFormat2))
            .toFormatter();
        DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(newFormat);